# Django password reset PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: python, django, django-views, passwords, reset-password

View:

```
def f_forget_password(request):
    ctx = dict()
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            to_email = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            to_email=to_email.lower()
            associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=to_email))
            if associated_users.exists():
                if len(associated_users)!=1:
                    return HttpResponse('Email Is Invalid.')
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                for user in associated_users:
                    mail_subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    email_template_name = "password/password_reset_email.txt"
                    uid=urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
                    c = {
                    "email":user.email,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'site_name': 'mysit',
                    "uid": uid,
                    "user": user,
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                    }
                    try:
                        message = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                        email = EmailMessage(  
                                    mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]  
                        )  
                        email.send() 
                    except Exception as e:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.<br/>')
                    return redirect ("/password_reset/done/")
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Email not found.')
    template = loader.get_template('password/forget_password.html')
    response = HttpResponse(template.render(ctx, request),content_type='text/html')
    return response
```

url:

```
path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>',
            auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), 
                 name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

token.py:

```
class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):  
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):  
        return (  
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +  
            six.text_type(user.is_active)  
        )  
account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

view PasswordResetConfirmView dont work and my password dont change.
when i clicked on passwordresetlink i have an Error:

> Password reset unsuccessful
>
> The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already
> been used. Please request a new password reset.

Comment: Share your `settings.py` file. I think, you should consider using `Sendgrid` server for `password reset` in `django` application.

Comment: I use my gmail to send email to client

Comment: I have error because of token.py I replace it with default_token_generator.make_token(user) and its now works, but anyone can tell why I got error

Comment: you have to note that `Gmail` does not use allow less secured app feature again as of `30th May 2022`, I do not agree with you saying: I use my `Gmail` to send email to client.

Comment: you have to change the way you are sending`Emails` to clients, from `Gmail` server to a `Emails` server like: `Mailjet` and `Sendgrid` or you will still getting an `errors` day after days.